# Showing HTML reports in CruiseControl dashboard

Tags: html, xml, cruisecontrol.net, documentation-generation, dashboard

I have been looking into CruiseControl configuration recently (I'm a complete CC noob) and so far I understand that various XML reports generated by your build process (eg mbunit.xml, ncover.xml, fxcop.xml) can be shown in the dashboard by adding a reference to the xml to the following part of the ccnet.config:

```
<publishers>
 <merge>
  <files>
   <file>logs\some-report.xml</file>
  </files>
 </merge>
</publish>
```

adding an xsl file to transform the xml into presentable html and adding a report build plugin to dashboard.config which references the xsl:

```
<xslReportBuildPlugin description="Some report"
actionName="SomeReportAction" xslFileName="xsl\some-report.xsl" />
```

My question is: if I have some reports (code documentation generated by JGregory's Docu and test specs generated by jpboodhoo's Bdddoc) which are pure HTML, is there any way I can show these in the dashboard in a similar way? I can't figure this out. I did think of adding an ExternalLink directly to the HTML page, but this is in a protected area which users normally cant access. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible in CruiseControl.NET up to version 1.4.4. However this functionality is being added as part of version 1.5.0.

We can't give you a timeframe on the release yet, but you can download and try out the latest version from http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/CCNet-builds/1.5.0/.

Craig

Comment: Thanks Craig I look forward to its release

Answer (score 2):

As craig already mentioned this functionality was added in CCNet 1.5, you'll find the documentation about the HtmlPlugin here: http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/HtmlReportPlugin